# ogr / osr for node.js / javascript

Tags: javascript, ogr, node-js

I use a python module I created that does tests for point in polygon.
It uses the python osgei/ogr and osr modules.

Specifically, I use the following elements of these modules:

```
osr.SpatialReference() (with ImportFromEPSG4326 and InputFromEPSG3857)
osr.CoordinateTransformation()
ogr.Geometry() (with ogr.wkbLinearRing, ogr.wkbPoint and ogr.wkbPolygon)
```

The software using these osr/ogr capabilities needs to be translated to be a node.js module.

Is anyone aware of an existing node.js osr/ogr 'wrapper' (or for generic javascript)?

Comment: The day you see `javascript` in [the `gdal/swig` directory](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig) is when this is possible. Post your interest on the `gdal-dev` email list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a node.js module and not just for ogr and osr but for the whole of gdal.  You can find the repository [here](https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal).

Comment: This is fantastic!